# JsonMappingException while using Inheritance in json request

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, aws-lambda

I have a requirement, a Lambda function should have generic input . based on  the input, it should perform logic specific to the type. 
Basically, there will be an interface, based on input json it should automatically map that to the corresponding subtype.

Here are my classes

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<DemographicRequest, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(DemographicRequest input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        if (input instanceof NameRequest) {
            context.getLogger().log("Name request");
            // name specific logic and update in db
        } else if (input instanceof AddressRequest) {
            context.getLogger().log("Address Request");
            //address specific logic and update in db
        }

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return "Hello from Lambda!";
    }

}

public class AddressRequest implements DemographicRequest {

    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String street;
    private String city; 
    private String zipCode;
    private String country;

// setter and getters

}

public class NameRequest implements DemographicRequest {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

//setters and getters
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = NameRequest.class), @Type(value = AddressRequest.class) })
public interface DemographicRequest {

}
```

when I try with input request below I am getting JsonMappingException. I have used @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes (not sure if used in a proper way). But still no use.

```
{
  "firstname": "fist",
  "lastname": "last"
}

Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.model.DemographicRequest, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@544fe44c; line: 1, column: 1]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.model.DemographicRequest, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@544fe44c; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:892)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:139)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)
```

Can you please help me to address/resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The error

> abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

means that Jackson can not parse the object based on the interface `DemographicRequest`. You have to provide the concrete classes `NameRequest`, `AddressRequest`.
The only thing a can think of if using a `RequestStreamHandler` and doing the deserialization "by hand". But I admit that this is not particularly elegant.
E.g.

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    @Override
    public void handler(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException, IOException {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + inputStream);

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            Object input = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, NameRequest.class);
            context.getLogger().log("Name request");
            // name specific logic and update in db
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            //
        }
        try {
            Object input = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, AddressRequest.class);
            context.getLogger().log("Address Request");
            //address specific logic and update in db
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            //
        }

        // TODO: implement your handler
        outputStream.write("Hello from Lambda!".getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    }

}
```

A better approach would probably be to provide a separate handler for each type.